# Where do I put my html and js code to publish microsoft word addin?

Tags: javascript, deployment, ms-word, add-in, office-addins

I have developed my first Microsoft Word add-in using OfficeDev/generator-office plain Javascript version. When I went to Microsoft app-source to publish my add-in, it asked me to upload only the "manifest.xml" file of my add-in. So what is the next step like where I have to upload the rest of the code? Can anybody guide me?